# Wrong design in the IE browser - JSP

Tags: html, jsp, internet-explorer

I have two JSP, the first one contains a table, the second one contains rows (`<tr>`) to be added to the table.

In the second JSP, I define the same action, then the `<tr>` to be added:

```
<html:form action="MyAction">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <nested:text property="myObject.myfield" maxlength="4" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</html:form>
```

The design in FF is fine, but in the IE I have a wrong one!
I feel that the new `<tr>` doesn't belong to the table.

Is it the cause of the definition of the action in the second JSP?
If so, what can be the solution?

[image]

Comment: For client-side debugging issues, please show the RENDERED HTML, not your server-side code.

Comment: Better: show us both sides. :)

Comment: @powerMock, I added an image which shows my problem :)

Comment: We need to see the HTML and CSS that the browser receives.

Comment: Which IE? 4? 11? All?

Comment: You don't have a table here. You have a form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem, I used another approach:

In my first jsp: before calling the second jsp, I add:

```
request.setAttribute("myObject", myObject);
```

Then the second jsp changed to be only:

```
<% Object myObject= (Object)request.getAttribute("parentRiskWeighting");%>
<tr>
    <td>
       <input type="text" class="input-tbl" value=" <%= myObject.myfield %> " maxlength="4" />
    </td>
</tr>
```